# Create a neural network with a matrix output

Tags: neural-networks

Is it possible to create a neural network that has a matrix as its output instead of a vector?

Or do I have to vectorize the matrix, i.e. make make one long vector instead of a matrix.

Comment: If you can define a loss function, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: True, pretty valid point.

Answer (score 4):

If you can define a loss function, you can do whatever you want.